# Process in Fedora Linux

Tags: c++, linux, process

I am new to fedora and just creating process in fedora using c++ code. I want to make 2 process from the parent process. I am doing so in my code but the When process 2 is created and I check its parent id it differ from the original parent Id can some tell why this code is showing this behavior thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout<<"Begning of the program"<<endl;
int counter=0;
pid_t child1=fork();



if(child1==0)
{

    cout<<"Child1 Process"<<endl;
    cout<<"Process ID: "<<getpid()<<endl;
    cout<<"Parrent ID: "<<getppid()<<endl;


}
else if(child1>0)
{
    pid_t child2=fork();
     if(child2>0)
     {
        cout<<"Parrent of Child1 and Child2"<<endl;
        cout<<"Process ID: "<<getpid()<<endl;
        cout<<"Parrent ID: "<<getppid()<<endl;

     }
    else if(child2==0)
     {
        cout<<"Child2 Creadted"<<endl;
        cout<<"Process ID: "<<getpid()<<endl;
        cout<<"Parrent ID: "<<getppid()<<endl;

     }

    else
    {
        cout<<"Process Failed"<<endl;
    }

}
else
{
        cout<<"Process fail"<<endl;

}

cout<<"End "<<endl;

return 0;

}
```

Results:

```
   Begning of the program
Parrent of Child1 and Child2
Child1 Process
Process ID: 2186
Parrent ID: 2059
End 
Process ID: 2187
Parrent ID: 2186
End 
Child2 Creadted
Process ID: 2188
Parrent ID: 1287
End
```

Comment: The output order between your three processes is not defined. You need to mark the output of `"Process ID"` and `"Parrent ID"` so you know which process they really came from.

Comment: More related to your problem, nowhere do you [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for the child processes to finish.

Comment: 1287 ?        00:00:00 systemd
this is the 1287 process

Comment: Some programmer dude where should I put the wait command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should apply wait after creating the process 2 like I do in the code. So that parent remain alive until the child 2 executes. In you r code parent dies after creating child2 which make child 2 a zombie process.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <spawn.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

    cout<<"Begning of the program"<<endl;
    int counter=0;
    pid_t child1=fork();



    if(child1==0)
    {

        cout<<"Child1 Process"<<endl;
        cout<<"Process ID: "<<getpid()<<endl;
        cout<<"Parrent ID: "<<getppid()<<endl;


    }
    else if(child1>0)
    {
        pid_t child2=fork();
        wait(NULL);
         if(child2>0)
         {
            cout<<"Parrent of Child1 and Child2"<<endl;
            cout<<"Process ID: "<<getpid()<<endl;
            cout<<"Parrent ID: "<<getppid()<<endl;

         }
        else if(child2==0)
         {
            cout<<"Child2 Creadted"<<endl;
            cout<<"Process ID: "<<getpid()<<endl;
            cout<<"Parrent ID: "<<getppid()<<endl;

         }

        else
        {
            cout<<"Process Failed"<<endl;
        }

    }
    else
    {
            cout<<"Process fail"<<endl;

    }

    cout<<"End "<<endl;

    return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Before your forked child process output its parent process id, the real parent (where `fork()` was called) already exited. The child process is reattached to the group parent process, which pid is output by the child.

You could call `pstree -p` to see which process is 1303.

I advise to replace lines

```
cout<<"Process ID: "<<getpid()<<endl;
cout<<"Parrent ID: "<<getppid()<<endl;
```

with

```
cout << getpid() << ": Parent ID: "<< getpid() << endl;
```

This would help to separate possible mixed outputs (since the output order is undetermined.) Example output:

```
2186: Parent ID: 2059
```

Comment: 1287 ? 00:00:00 systemd this is the 1287 process  
now what can I do to get the correct parrent id of child 2?

Comment: `systemd` is ok. It is the starting root of all user processes. You can call `waitpid` in the parent for waiting a child process, thus the parent will be alive in idle untill child exits.